# Ruby on Rails 4 controllers subfolders for specific related functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

is there any way to keep a group of Rails 4 controllers or models in a specific subfolder inside controllers? (because they all match a concrete related functionality)

Comment: Yes, if you use a controller namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As @sevenseacat said solution is namespaces.

More detailed answer here: [Rails Controller Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22913318/rails-controller-namespace)